# Issue in deserializing of List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>

Tags: apex, email, json, future, deserialize

I would like to send email with future apex. Because of future method can't access list of Messaging.SingleEmailMessage, I'm serializing it and pass string to future method. But when I deserialize it, I get  System.JSONException: Unrecognized field "debug". When I debugged my string, I saw this:
[{"bccAddresses":null,"bccSender":false,"ccAddresses":null,"charset":null,"debug":"bccSender: false, saveAsActivity: false, useSignature: false, targetObjectId: 0053X00000BYHeOQAX, whatId: 0Q05t000000CnrnCAC, templateId: 00X3X00000312ixUAA,...

The piece with "debug" doesn't look correct... How can I fix it?
My code :

```
   private static void sendEmailToApprover(Map<Id,Quote> newMap, Map<Id,Quote> oldMap) {
        Map<Quote, Id> quoteToApproverId = new Map<Quote, Id>();
        Map<Quote, User> quoteToApprover= new Map<Quote, User>();
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messagesList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Map<String, String> clevelUserToEmail = new Map<String, String>();
        for(Quote quote : newMap.values()) {
            if(quote.ApproverID__c != oldMap.get(quote.Id).ApproverID__c && quote.ApproverID__c != null) {
                quoteToApproverId.put(quote,quote.ApproverID__c);
            }
        }
        if(!quoteToApproverId.isEmpty()) {
            EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id, Name, Subject, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = :QUOTE_APPROVSL_TEMPLATE_NAME];
            Map<Id, User> approvers = new Map<Id, User>(queryUsersByUserIds(new Set<Id>(quoteToApproverId.values())));
            for(Quote quote : quoteToApproverId.keySet()) {
                    quoteToApprover.put(quote, approvers.get(quote.ApproverID__c));
            }
            List<User> clevelUsers = [SELECT Id, Email, User.Name FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = :C_LEVEL ];
            for(User user : clevelUsers) {
                clevelUserToEmail.put(user.Name, user.Email);
            }

            for(Quote quote : quoteToApproverId.keySet()) {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
                mail.setTargetObjectId(quote.ApproverID__c);
                if(quoteToApprover.get(quote).Name == CPO) {
                    mail.setCcAddresses(new List<String>{clevelUserToEmail.get(CCO)});
                }
                else if(quoteToApprover.get(quote).Name == CEO) {
                    mail.setCcAddresses(new List<String>{clevelUserToEmail.get(CCO)});
                    mail.setBCcAddresses(new List<String>{clevelUserToEmail.get(CPO)});
                }
                mail.setWhatId(quote.Id);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                mail.setUseSignature(false);
                mail.setBccSender(false);
                messagesList.add(mail);
            }
            String s = JSON.serialize(messagesList);
            sendEmail(s);  
        }         
    }

 

    @future(callout=false) private static void sendEmail(String message) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messagesList = (List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>) JSON.deserialize(message, List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>.class);
        if (!messagesList?.isEmpty()) {
                Messaging.sendEmail(messagesList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use the real `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` but instead provide a data object of your own that you turn back into the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` instances on the other side of the call. There are many Salesforce API classes that do not support JSON  serialization/deserialization. You normally get an error at serialisation time though, rather than bad JSON. BTW, why not use a Queueable to avoid serialisation completely? May still require your data object class.